# When do I need to use in-memory datastructures instead of an SQL query?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, nosql

What I aim to do as an end result is for the user to be able type into something like a textbox and a variety of options to appear as the user types letters.
As an example the user could start typing a name e.g. `Jam` and underneath nearest suggestions e.g. `James`, `Jameson`, `Jamie` etc would appear.
I know that if I use SQL's `SELECT LIKE %Jam%` could do the job (although I guess the user would have to stop writing to be able to execute the query; so the user *can not* actually see suggestions as he types.Right?).
But for my scope I would not need to use an RDBMS since the data are small and don't have real relationships between them.
I thought of using some NoSQL solution so that I look into this technology (never used it before), but in this case I am not sure on how to approach a design such as this.
Should I build a tree pre-loading all the data in the storage? So I have the data both in-memory and in-storage? But if I use a NoSQL solution isn't that usually in-memory? So I have the same data in-memory twice?
Any help on how could I approach a problem like this?

Comment: If the data items to search into are few enough (and more importantly, you can be sure they won't increase wildly over time), I see nothing wrong with caching them in memory (but provide a method to update them if they change in the DB). Additionally, what you could do is to launch the predictive search only if the user stops writting for a time (say 500 ms.) to avoid unnecessary SQL queries.

Comment: And be sure to use a minimum of character introduced to avoid excessive results (so no search is triggered if the user only writes `J`)

Comment: 1)So you recommend an RDBMS? 2)I am interested also to learn how similar problems of larger datasets are solved

Comment: I just gave a few tips/alternatives that might be useful. They may not be enough for your case, so I wrote them as comment rather than answer. Maybe in your case the proper answer is to ditch the RDBMS altogether, but I would explore the easier options faster.

Comment: As for larger datasets, do not forget to limit the size of your results (for example, get only the 20 most recent records, or the values more repeated, or even 20 random records). If the searched record is not there, the user has to keep typing. You don't want a popup with 100,000 names in your GUI, no matter how fast you get them from storage because you will need too much memory, and it won't be useful for your users anyway.

Comment: These are interesting ideas, but my core problem is how to design this. So you also agree that I would need an inmemory datastructure for this?Or should this be handled by the database?Is a NoSQL a good solution here?

Comment: I think this is much more a UI/UX issue than a database (or memory vs. disk) issue.

Comment: @Catcall:I haven't got the experience in such a design, that is why I ask

Comment: @user384706: See Science_Fiction's answer below, and http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @Catcall:I am not interested in using something like that. I would prefer doing something myself for my practice.If possible that is.Or at least learn what is the best way to this, not just pick a random library that seems to do the trick

Comment: @user384706: Doing things yourself is probably the best way to learn, but it can be inefficient for complex problems that have already been solved.

Comment: @Catcall:Good point.But in my case I still am not sure how should I not re-implement things and follow a standard approach.E.g. is a NoSQL a good approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

Guessing you need some Asynchronous Ajax or JQuery [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) command to fetch the like items from your DB.

If its Java Swing have a look at [this](http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to your original question, I think your goals are in conflict.

If you want to learn by doing, you risk reinventing the wheel. You also risk *trying* to reinvent the wheel, but ending up instead with a square wheel that won't roll.

This isn't necessarily a bad thing. You can learn a lot this way, but this kind of learning conflicts with your following statement.

> ...I still am not sure how should I not re-implement things and follow
>   a standard approach.E.g. is a NoSQL a good approach for this?

The only thing that comes close to a standard approach here is to store the data on a server, not on the client.  There are a *lot* of ways to do that, and if you object to picking "a random library that seems to do the trick", you ought also to object to picking "a random database technology that seems to do the trick".

I think the best way to learn in this case is to build your software in such a way that it knows nothing about how the data is stored on the back end.  That way, you can swap out text files, a SQL dbms, a NoSQL dbms, and anything else you can dream up without affecting the front end code at all.

*That's* good software design--loose coupling between front end and back end.

Comment: OK.I'll ask it differently:`That way, you can swap out text files, a SQL dbms, a NoSQL...`.But the presentation of all posibilities to the user must be done somewhere higher than the level you are talking about.For example using a tree is AFAIK the correct datastructure to show related options.But do I construct the in-memory tree each time? Do I cache it? Do I need not use a tree at all and do queries to SQL server? These are my questions.Also note that I have not used NoSQL at all and know very little about it.That is why am asking if it is a fit

Comment: "For example using a tree is AFAIK the correct datastructure to show related options." It's one of many data structures that you can use to store completed terms. You can construct a tree each time, or you can construct something once and store it. You can cache on the front- or back-end. You can query a server whenever you like. There isn't one right answer for you. To present data to the user, your data structure has to mate with whatever kind of control will be doing the presentation. You might want to give that some thought first.